# Passing integer value to glUniformSubroutinesuiv

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm collecting my first experience with subroutines in GLSL shaders. I'm using a two-pass edge detection shader, which renders the scene to a texture in the first pass and then overlays the edges in the second pass. The fragment shader has the following two subroutines and looks like this:

```
#version 430

/* Subroutines */
subroutine vec4 RenderPassType();
layout (location = 0) subroutine uniform RenderPassType renderPass;
...

layout (index = 1) subroutine(RenderPassType)
vec4 pass1()
{
    ...
}

layout (index = 2) subroutine(RenderPassType)
vec4 pass2()
{
    ...
}

void main()
{
    out_color = renderPass();
}
```

In my OpenGL code, I retrieve the index of the subroutines and set the subroutine uniform in the following way:

```
GLuint subroutineIndexPass1{0};
GLuint subroutineIndexPass2{0};
subroutineIndexPass1 = glGetSubroutineIndex(prg_phongShading->GetProgramHandle(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "pass1");       
subroutineIndexPass2 = glGetSubroutineIndex(prg_phongShading->GetProgramHandle(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "pass2");

glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, &subroutineIndexPass1);
```

However, I already defined the index in the shader itself as a layout specifier! And I can't do this:

```
glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, 1);
```

Therefore my question is: how do I pass the integer literal value to `glUniformSubroutinesuiv`? Is there a more elegant solution than specifying `GLuint index = 1` and pass this as argument to the function?

Comment: I find your question confusing. How do you know what the index is for a subroutine when you set its index? That sounds like a Zen Koan. You assigned it a number. You therefore know what number you assigned it, because *you* were the one who *assigned* it. That's the whole point of in-shader specification; you don't have to ask what the indices are because *you set them*.

Comment: Exactly! But so far I couldn't figure out how to make the call to `glUniformSubroutinesuiv` knowing the (manually-set) index which I would like to use. I can't just use `glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, 1)`. Is there a more elegant solution than specifying `GLuint index = 1` and pass this as argument to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant solution than specifying `GLuint index = 1` and pass this as argument to the function?

No.

Comment: Plain and simple. Though I don't see any scenario where it would be beneficial to directly specify the index inside the shader, querying for the index seems somehow more error proof to me.

Comment: You could write your own wrapper function that takes an index by value.